# Guzzle POST request not working

Tags: php, json, post, guzzle, google-url-shortener

I would like to use [Google URL Shortener API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#shorten). Now, I need to send a JSON POST request to the Google API.

I'm using Guzzle 6.2 in PHP.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$google_api_key =  'AIzaSyBKOBhDQ8XBxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$body = '{"longUrl" : "http://www.google.com"}';
$res = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url', [
      'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
      'form_params' => [
            'key'=>$google_api_key
       ],
       'body' => $body
]);
return $res;
```

But it returns following error :

```
Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "parseError",
"message": "Parse Error"
}
(truncated...)
```

Any helps would be appreciated. I've read Guzzle document and many other resources but didn't help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `form_params`, because Google requires simple GET parameter, not POST (and you can not even do that, because you have to choose between body types: `form_params` creates `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body, and `body` parameter creates raw body).

So simply replace `form_params` with `query`:

```
$res = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url', [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
    'query' => [
        'key' => $google_api_key
    ],
    'body' => $body
]);

// Response body content (JSON string).
$responseJson = $res->getBody()->getContents();
// Response body content as PHP array.
$responseData = json_decode($responseJson, true);
```

Comment: Response JSON is in the response body. Call `$res->getBody()->getContents()` to see it.

Comment: You are awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt able to make a post request, is not exactly the same case but I write here my solution in case helps someone:

I needed to send a post request with a key like this 'request_data', I was trying to do it as Guzzle docs say:

```
 $r = $client->request('PUT', 'http://test.com', [
'form_data' => ['request_data' => 'xxxxxxx']
 ]);
```

the result was something like this:

```
{'request_data':....}
```

but what I wanted was something like this:

```
 'request_data': {}
```

so what I finally figure it out was doing it like this:

```
    $client = new Client();

    $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'body' => "request_data=" . json_encode([$yourData]),
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ]
    ]);
```

doing it like this the result is what I expected.

Answer (score -1):

The manual says the following:

> After you have an API key, your application can append the query parameter key=yourAPIKey to all request URLs.

Try to append `"key=$google_api_key" to your URL.

Comment: And what about `form_params`  part?